# Spring beans value injection

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I'm starting work with the Spring framework and I'm trying to wrap my head around the beans concept.
I have an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id= "currentDateService" class ="xx.CurrentDateSerivceimpl" />
</beans>
```

And a class to get the current date:

```
public class CurrentDateServiceImpl implements CurrentDateService {
    public LocalDate getCurrentDate() {
        return LocalDate.now() ;

    }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a simple @test to assert if the bean value is the same as the current date i supply.

What I'm stuck at is:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    CurrentDateServiceImpl currentDateServiceObj = (CurrentDateServiceImpl) context.getBean("currentDateService");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate date2 = "the value of the bean";
    assertEquals(date, date2);
}
```

I'm unaware of how i can supply the value of the bean in to the test, and i was wondering how to accomplish it and if there was any good tutorials/documentations except for the spring docs themselves

Edit:

```
package lt.insoft.app.bl.service.impl;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import lt.insoft.app.bl.service.CurrentDateService;
import lt.insoft.app.bl.service.CurrentDateServiceFormat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/resources/META-INF/application-context.xml" })
public class CurrentDateServiceImplTest {

@Autowired
CurrentDateService service; 
CurrentDateServiceFormat service2;


    @Test
    public void test() {

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate date2 = service.getCurrentDate();     
        String date3 = service2.formatCurrentDate();
        System.out.println(date3);
        assertEquals(date, date2);
    }

}
```

Why is this not printing the formatted date?

Comment: Simply call `currentDateServiceObj.getCurrentDate()`

Comment: There's no need to do everything by hand. For new code, I generally recommend JavaConfig over XML, and certainly injection to bean lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spring support for testing. Code will be cleaner and easyer to understand.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"application-context.xml"})
public class TestClass{

@Autowired
CurrentDateService service;

@Test
public void test() {

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate date2 = service.getCurrentDate();
    assertEquals(date, date2);
}
}
```

I think you wanted to do something like this:

```
public class CurrentDateServiceImpl implements CurrentDateService {
    public LocalDate getCurrentDate() {
        return LocalDate.now() ;

    }
}

public class CurrentDateServiceFormatImpl implements CurrentDateServiceFormat{
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

    CurrentDateService service;

    public void myMethod(){
       return service.getCurrentDate().format(FORMATTER); 
    }

    public void setService(CurrentDateService service){
       this.service = service;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id= "currentDateService" class ="xx.CurrentDateSerivceimpl" />
  <bean id= "CurrentDateServiceFormat" class ="xx.CurrentDateServiceFormatImpl">
     <property name="service" id-ref="currentDateService"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you, although i have a follow up question, it seems that I'm not understanding what a bean really is, should i post the question further on here?

Comment: Ok, let me try to exmplain. In normal java application(console) You have to create and pass many class instances. In Spring you don't have to. You tell spring (in xml definitions) how to create z java class (for example: what arguments it have), and then when you are creating a bean, you can simply ask Spring to give you instance of your class. So you are creating a container made of java instances (Beans) and you can use them to fill your class (other Beans) needs.
You can google "dependency injection" for more info on this topic.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is how to transfer value between beans, for example i get the Local date and im trying to change the format of it:


public String CurrentDateServiceFormat(){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter);
    return formattedDateTime;
}


and the dateTime should be equal the the value of the previous bean, which is by my understanding the current date that i obtained with the getCurrentDate method? But how can i now supply it to the next method

Comment: I seem to understand how the values change, but for some reason I'm unable to run a test
The test class: